# Programatically changing the line ending in a legend control,c#

Tags: html, legend

All,
  I am using an HTML  control in my asp.net app.I run this as a server control and programatically access this from my code behind(C#) class.Plase see the markup.
. The innerHTML property is set dynamically from code.My issue is if the InnerHTML is really long , i set line breaks at specific char intervals. That looks ok except for  the horizontal line that appears between the text.

I need to display text like this

```
-----------This is my name 
blah blahhhhhh------------------
```

but right now it displays as

```
--------This is my name---------------
         blah blah blah
```

Is there a way to set the line programaticcaly or using style?
thanks for help

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but not what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a few things :

- set the width of your control so the text inside wraps automatically to the next line
- Edit the content of the control, inserting line breaks where needed

There's no method to automatically transform text as your example shows. It is possible, but you might need to write it yourself.

A warning here : you can measure the letters easily with `"string".Length` but it gives no guarantee to the actual width, in pixels, of the string (consider `"iii"` takes less room than `"www"` in non-fixed width fonts). If you want to measure pixels, it gets complicated fast, so your better off measuring the number of letters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it with styles:

```
<div style="width:300px;text-align:right;">This is my name </div>
<div style="width:300px;text-align:left;">blah blahhhhhh</div>
```